# Intellij IDEA: How to auto-import java packages than "import package.SpecificClass"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When using Intellij IDEA's auto importing feature, how to make it import packages rather than individual classes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `Preferences->Project Settings->Code Style->Java` select `Imports` tab. Uncheck `USe Single Class Imports`. Set `Class count to use import with *` to 1.

Comment: just exactly what i expected